# Is there a way to get the URL of the Google App Engine instance of a project in the GitHub PR flow?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, pipeline

We'd like for the PR approval for an application created in Google App Engine to return the project version URL to display in GitHub (so this can be passed on to the test team as a standalone entity). Not sure if this is actually possible. Has anyone had any luck doing this before?

So far, I have not been able to find any documentation for this, although plenty helping to connect GitHub processes to GCP.

Comment: You must create first and deploy your app/service in order to get the URL of the App Engine instance. Check these docs regarding the two environments of app engine: [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service) and [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/create-app). Once your app is running in App Engine, you can use the [URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-requests-are-routed?tab=node.js#urls). Then check this [github actions](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine).

Comment: Thanks Sarah! deploy-appengine was exactly what I needed :)